# Spring Data JPA not filtering by child collection attribute with query method name

Tags: java, spring, jpa

So I have a class with an attribute that consists of a list of another class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<PersonValue> personValues;

// getters/setters
}
```

And a PersonValue class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_values")
public class PersonValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long personValueId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // getters/setters
}
```

And a City class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer cityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // getters/setters
}
```

By using query method name to filter the Persons I need to retrieve by the city_id of it's PersonValues I get a Set with PersonValues of not only the city I passed it's city_id as a parameter for the method:

```
public interface PersonDAO extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    Set<Person> findByPersonValuesCityCityIdOrderByStateNameAscNameAscPersonValuesNameAsc(Integer cityId);
}
```

So in an example, I passed city_id 3375 and it returned a Person with a PersonValues list with not only this city (3375) but other ones as well.

Any idea why this happens and how can I fix it?

It was also returning multiple duplicated persons in the list till I changed the return type from List to Set.

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. You need a mappedBy="person" on the OneToMany. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Edit: Added mappedBy="person" and removed the @JoinColumn from list of personValues attribute, kept it on the PersonValue's attribute (Person) or it just wouldn't find the correct column
Still returning personValues that is from a different city than the one with city_id 3375
Added the configuration to show the SQL (spring.jpa.show-sql=true) and it gets the persons by the city_id with a join (person join person_values join cities) and uses the returned persons to query for person_values, but filtering with it's person_id without the city_id as filter

Comment: You could back map the person values and person and select the city using a simple findBy() and in your java code back track  city.getPersonValue().getPerson() or something...

Comment: I know a long time has passed, but I'm facing the same issue, @Alexandre did you get to fix this issue?